# Content Before first p

Tags: css

Before only in the first paragraph

I try to do the following:

```html
.answer p::first-letter:before{
     content:'A';

}
```

How could you achieve the desired result.

I try to place the content only in the first paragraph of the container, which I think is like this:

```html
nswer p:first-child:before{
     content:'R';}
```

But it does not respect the first paragraph, but instead includes it in others in the same container.

Comment: Your question is really not clear, but you can read the documentation on what you need : https://css-tricks.com/css-content/

Comment: Please explain what your `desired result` would be, because I can't see that in your question. Give examples of HTML and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply need to insert something before a `<p>` element, then there is no need to specify the `::first-letter` pseudo selector. A simple `:before` is enough.

```css
.container > p:first-child:before {
  content: "A";
}

.container > p:not(first-child) {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>typical</p>
  <p>typical</p>
  <p>typical</p>
</div>
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/zYNdzQG).

Answer (score 0):

CSS is very specific, it will alter what you are selecting. If you want to change something before the first `<p>` in your html you should try and find that in your html and write a css selector for that element i.e. is if a `<div>` what is the class name of that div - that is what you want to select with the css. Maybe create a div, add a class name to it, put your `<p>` into it and write css for that new class. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you mean, but if its just the first paragraph you want a `:before` on then just add the class to your first `p`;

```
<div>
<p class="first_paragraph">
 This is paragraph 1
</p>

<p>
 this is paragraph 2

</p>
</div>
```

then apply your content.

```
.first_paragraph:before {
  content: 'A_1';
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3y0umngk/)

Alternatively, if your content is dynamic and you cant apply the css.

Then you can use the `first-child` combined with the `before`.

```
.paragraph_list p:first-child:before {
  content: 'A_1';
}
```

[Second Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3y0umngk/1/)

Comment: I have updated the question.

I use Wordpress and I can't add the class to p. Thanks

Comment: So use the second example I gave.

Answer (score 0):

You were close!

Try this:

```
.answer p:first-child:before{
     content:'A';
}
```